# How to write variables to stm32 flash memory

Tags: stm32, flash-memory

I want to declare a variable in flash memory in stm32 so that the variable value I modified remains when the board is powered off and on, how can I write a variable in flash memory?

Chatgpt told me to go to properties and do something on the symbol tab, but I don't have the symbol tab, so something's stuck

---

Environment

CUBE IDE - C Language

### STM32H743XIH6

---

How do I write variables in flash memory?
First, we're going to write the variable types int, unsigned char, and uint8_t

Please tell us about websites and methods that are good for reference

Comment: There's no simple way to store a variable in flash memory. Flash memory can be erased (generally page at a time, e.g. 2048 bytes), which typically sets all the bits in each word (e.g. to 0xffffffff). From there, the only thing you can do is clear bits by programming them. If you want to set a bit, you'd need to erase the page again. But each page can only be erased a finite number of times.

Comment: Do not think that chatGPT will replace the knowledge required. What you need to do: 1. Download your micro ***Reference manual***. 2. Read about FLASH memory controller.. 3. Write the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STM32F745 - HAL\_FLASH\_Program not writing to flash permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509933/stm32f745-hal-flash-program-not-writing-to-flash-permanently)